# Potential MySQL Buffer Problem? Need Help Debugging

Tags: php, mysql, select, buffer, fetch

From the middle of a script I've been able to isolate a (very sudden) issue with querying some data from MySQL using PHP.  Using the same connection within the same API in the past, I have been able to do numerous (millions of) individual INSERT queries in the past.  Also, I've been able to return and manipulate large SELECT result sets.

However, the following error has been occurring.  The following returns 54265:

```
$status = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table_Name", $t_conn) or die("bad query");
echo mysql_num_rows($status);
```

And then, attempting the following stops at 23494:

```
$status = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table_Name", $t_conn) or die("bad query");
$i = 0;
while($dataset = mysql_fetch_assoc($status)) {
    echo $i++."<br />\n";
}
```

The odd thing is that it matters whether or not I am saving the fetched data.  The following stops at 6494:

```
$status = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table_Name", $t_conn) or die("bad query");
$i = 0;
$dataset = array();
while($dataset[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($status)) {
    echo $i++."<br />\n";
}
```

This leads me to believe that I have an error with Apache or PHP.  Looking at /var/log/system.log, the last line is:

```
Aug 17 11:43:51 zirkel com.apple.ReportCrash.Root[1862]: 2010-08-17 11:43:51.936 ReportCrash[1862:2903] Saved crash report for httpd[1263] version ??? (???) to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/httpd_2010-08-17-114351_localhost.crash
```

Looking at the crash report yields:

```
Process:         httpd [1263]
Path:            /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd
Identifier:      httpd
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  httpd [417]

Date/Time:       2010-08-17 11:43:51.006 -0600
OS Version:      Mac OS X Server 10.6.4 (10F569)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libphp5.so                          0x00000001012abcfa mysqlnd_palloc_zval_ptr_dtor + 75 (mysqlnd_palloc.c:420)
1   libphp5.so                          0x00000001012ae74c mysqlnd_free_buffered_data + 165 (mysqlnd_result.c:216)
2   libphp5.so                          0x00000001012ae915 php_mysqlnd_res_free_result_buffers_pub + 69 (mysqlnd_result.c:340)
3   libphp5.so                          0x00000001012ae975 mysqlnd_internal_free_result_contents + 18 (mysqlnd_result.c:373)
4   libphp5.so                          0x00000001012adf7b mysqlnd_internal_free_result + 18 (mysqlnd_result.c:396)
5   libphp5.so                          0x00000001012adcf9 php_mysqlnd_res_free_result_pub + 89 (mysqlnd_result.c:1686)
6   libphp5.so                          0x00000001011456c2 _free_mysql_result + 18 (php_mysql.c:321)
7   libphp5.so                          0x000000010130ecdf list_entry_destructor + 81 (zend_list.c:184)
8   libphp5.so                          0x000000010130c048 zend_hash_apply_deleter + 198 (zend_hash.c:613)
9   libphp5.so                          0x000000010130c0f1 zend_hash_graceful_reverse_destroy + 22 (zend_hash.c:647)
10  libphp5.so                          0x00000001013012eb zend_deactivate + 188 (zend.c:899)
11  libphp5.so                          0x00000001012b5c54 php_request_shutdown + 589 (main.c:1605)
12  libphp5.so                          0x000000010137b5cd php_handler + 1373 (sapi_apache2.c:661)
13  httpd                               0x00000001000038af ap_invoke_handler + 267
14  httpd                               0x000000010002cfc3 ap_process_request + 87
15  httpd                               0x0000000100029ec8 ap_process_http_connection + 98
16  httpd                               0x000000010000cb42 ap_process_connection + 161
17  httpd                               0x0000000100045b85 child_main + 1135
18  httpd                               0x0000000100045d11 make_child + 292
19  httpd                               0x0000000100046aea ap_mpm_run + 1980
20  httpd                               0x0000000100006e52 main + 3254
21  httpd                               0x00000001000009c4 start + 52

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00000000ffffffff  rbx: 0x0000000101b1a3b0  rcx: 0x00007fff5fbff27f  rdx: 0x0000000000000001
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000101c76280  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbff240  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbff220
   r8: 0x0000000000000001   r9: 0x0000000102a66900  r10: 0x0000000102afc0a4  r11: 0x0000000102a66690
  r12: 0x00007fff5fbff27f  r13: 0x0000000104c497e0  r14: 0x0000000101c76280  r15: 0x0000000101c76280
  rip: 0x00000001012abcfa  rfl: 0x0000000000000282  cr2: 0x0000000000000010

Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x10006efef +httpd ??? (???) <5AD55ACB-737F-7C6B-17EA-FFE7A3169DAB> /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd
       0x1000ba000 -        0x1000d2fe7  libaprutil-1.0.dylib 4.9.0 (compatibility 4.0.0) <3D7EBE21-7A3D-E46C-1E3E-361F98170429> /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib
       0x1000dd000 -        0x1000fbfff  libapr-1.0.dylib 4.8.0 (compatibility 4.0.0) <77712CC8-C4CF-E0E8-B740-B55192C05CB9> /usr/lib/libapr-1.0.dylib
       0x100127000 -        0x100134fe7  libexslt.0.dylib 9.13.0 (compatibility 9.0.0) <D9944F04-1F01-B9D1-A46F-96229CD19437> /usr/lib/libexslt.0.dylib
       0x10013a000 -        0x10017dff7  libiodbc.2.dylib 4.18.0 (compatibility 4.0.0) <E8B6477A-E3BA-B781-6D7E-2C7118EA2ABD> /usr/lib/libiodbc.2.dylib
       0x100188000 -        0x100194fe7 +libXpm.4.dylib 16.0.0 (compatibility 16.0.0) <23481E29-B977-609A-B26B-6554B9271E40> /usr/X11/lib/libXpm.4.dylib
       0x10019a000 -        0x1001b7fff +libpng14.14.dylib 17.0.0 (compatibility 17.0.0) <BD58028C-5C1D-EFC0-C0AF-4128FD780A88> /usr/local/lib/libpng14.14.dylib
       0x1001c6000 -        0x1001eeff7  libpcre.0.dylib 1.1.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <2D8EFD51-1AFF-8B17-CD9F-F05994817685> /usr/lib/libpcre.0.dylib
       0x1001f3000 -        0x1001f4ff7 +libXau.6.dylib 7.0.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <BC858886-138B-D7D3-48CE-E9EFA56747E8> /usr/X11/lib/libXau.6.dylib
       0x1001f8000 -        0x1001fbfef +libXdmcp.6.dylib 7.0.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <EEC19E9E-A303-01DF-D05A-2EB65054242C> /usr/X11/lib/libXdmcp.6.dylib
       0x100300000 -        0x10036ffe7 +libfreetype.6.dylib 10.20.0 (compatibility 10.0.0) <565F62BF-96ED-57C4-C80E-0ECF9557408B> /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
       0x10039c000 -        0x1004adff7 +libX11.6.dylib 9.0.0 (compatibility 9.0.0) <1363DEB7-B718-202D-537F-B0769D6A329C> /usr/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
       0x1004d3000 -        0x100504ff4 +libjpeg.8.dylib 9.1.0 (compatibility 9.0.0) <152178F6-2055-1CE5-2197-70C8C6372576> /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
       0x100513000 -        0x10058dff7  libnetsnmp.15.dylib 17.2.0 (compatibility 17.0.0) <2BE5579E-2ADF-2930-FA8E-02E9CBB101E3> /usr/lib/libnetsnmp.15.dylib
       0x101000000 -        0x101804fff  libphp5.so ??? (???) <DCAADC90-170D-2735-3E1A-F484F7CA9184> /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
    0x7fff5fc00000 -     0x7fff5fc3bdef  dyld 132.1 (???) <B536F2F1-9DF1-3B6C-1C2C-9075EA219A06> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff80082000 -     0x7fff8041bff7  com.apple.QuartzCore 1.6.2 (227.22) <76EE0A32-B20B-F316-ADDD-4230329253D5> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
    0x7fff8041c000 -     0x7fff8041dff7  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent 1.1 (1) <51867586-1C71-AE37-EAAD-535A58DD3550> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff8041e000 -     0x7fff8045ffff  com.apple.SystemConfiguration 1.10.2 (1.10.2) <BC27BDD4-9CC8-9AF0-B4C2-DD50FD751CBF> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff80460000 -     0x7fff80577fef  libxml2.2.dylib 10.3.0 (compatibility 10.0.0) <EE067D7E-15B3-F043-6FBD-10BA31FE76C7> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x7fff80a3e000 -     0x7fff80a41ff7  com.apple.securityhi 4.0 (36638) <38935851-09E4-DDAB-DB1D-30ADC39F7ED0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI
    0x7fff80f47000 -     0x7fff81017ff7  com.apple.CFNetwork 454.9.7 (454.9.7) <AA6EB690-6CCF-603D-AAC2-35B9E05D1593> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff81070000 -     0x7fff81100fff  com.apple.SearchKit 1.3.0 (1.3.0) <4175DC31-1506-228A-08FD-C704AC9DF642> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff8112f000 -     0x7fff81145ff7  com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework 204.13 (204.13) <BFFEC259-F103-B25A-BB52-1AA79116DDBA> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
    0x7fff81211000 -     0x7fff81260ff7  com.apple.DirectoryService.PasswordServerFramework 6.0 (6.0) <14FD0978-4BE0-336B-A19E-F388694583EB> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PasswordServer.framework/Versions/A/PasswordServer
    0x7fff81261000 -     0x7fff812cbfe7  libvMisc.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <75A8D840-4ACE-6560-0889-2AFB6BE08E59> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff8143b000 -     0x7fff8145cfff  libresolv.9.dylib 41.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <6993F348-428F-C97E-7A84-7BD2EDC46A62> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x7fff820d9000 -     0x7fff820dcfff  com.apple.help 1.3.1 (41) <54B79BA2-B71B-268E-8752-5C8EE00E49E4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Help.framework/Versions/A/Help
    0x7fff820dd000 -     0x7fff8213bff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit 2.0 (???) <010C3398-7363-8F4B-719C-263867F15F63> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff8214e000 -     0x7fff82167fff  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <0F46E102-8B8E-0995-BA85-3D9608F0A30C> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
    0x7fff82168000 -     0x7fff8218bfff  com.apple.opencl 12.1 (12.1) <403E8F37-4348-B9BC-08E6-7693A995B7EC> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
    0x7fff8222f000 -     0x7fff82270fef  com.apple.QD 3.35 (???) <78C9A560-E6F7-DC4F-F85E-E63CF8A98F0B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
    0x7fff82271000 -     0x7fff82320fff  edu.mit.Kerberos 6.5.10 (6.5.10) <F3F76EDF-5660-78F0-FE6E-33B6174F55A4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
    0x7fff8238f000 -     0x7fff823defef  libTIFF.dylib ??? (???) <A66CBA9C-A38D-5EDB-BFB5-CB398F033D6F> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
    0x7fff823e4000 -     0x7fff823ebfff  com.apple.OpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <72A65D76-7831-D31E-F1B3-9E48BF26A98B> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
    0x7fff823ec000 -     0x7fff823f2ff7  IOSurface ??? (???) <EB2019F6-7C5C-3D59-E11F-6119466C12A9> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
    0x7fff823f3000 -     0x7fff8243dff7  com.apple.Metadata 10.6.3 (507.10) <641395B7-FF2C-B94C-965A-CE6A0830645F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff8246e000 -     0x7fff82472ff7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <95718673-FEEE-B6ED-B127-BCDBDB60D4E5> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
    0x7fff82473000 -     0x7fff82491fff  libPng.dylib ??? (???) <F6932C8D-E6B1-0871-B698-15180AA948F7> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
    0x7fff82519000 -     0x7fff82560ff7  com.apple.coreui 2 (114) <D7645B59-0431-6283-7322-957D944DAB21> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
    0x7fff825e0000 -     0x7fff82611fff  libGLImage.dylib ??? (???) <2F18DB77-CF77-1311-9E20-FE460090C166> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
    0x7fff8262e000 -     0x7fff827e4fef  com.apple.ImageIO.framework 3.0.3 (3.0.3) <A32D0B5A-7149-7739-22D3-84D38B07E9E5> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
    0x7fff827e5000 -     0x7fff82831fff  libauto.dylib ??? (???) <072804DF-36AD-2DBE-7EF8-639CFB79077F> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff82971000 -     0x7fff829acfff  com.apple.AE 496.4 (496.4) <CBEDB6A1-FD85-F842-4EB8-CC289FAE0F24> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff833a4000 -     0x7fff833b5ff7  libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility 1.0.0) <FB5EE53A-0534-0FFA-B2ED-486609433717> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff833c5000 -     0x7fff833fdff7  libssl.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8) <94776929-EF76-D979-5412-940C845BAC5D> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff83485000 -     0x7fff83485ff7  com.apple.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <08D3D45D-908B-B86A-00BA-0F978D2702A7> /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff8348e000 -     0x7fff834a0fe7  libsasl2.2.dylib 3.15.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <76B83C8D-8EFE-4467-0F75-275648AFED97> /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
    0x7fff838c2000 -     0x7fff838c2ff7  com.apple.Accelerate 1.6 (Accelerate 1.6) <2BB7D669-4B40-6A52-ADBD-DA4DB3BC0B1B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff838d1000 -     0x7fff8394efef  libstdc++.6.dylib 7.9.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <35ECA411-2C08-FD7D-11B1-1B7A04921A5C> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x7fff8394f000 -     0x7fff83b0dfff  libicucore.A.dylib 40.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <0E53A4A6-AC06-1B61-2285-248F534EE356> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff83b13000 -     0x7fff83b27fff  libGL.dylib ??? (???) <5AD69545-D1A3-C017-C7AF-B4AFD6F08FA2> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
    0x7fff83b28000 -     0x7fff83b36ff7  libkxld.dylib ??? (???) <EE840168-1F67-6219-8BA3-C46039BCC8B3> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
    0x7fff83b37000 -     0x7fff83b3cfff  libGIF.dylib ??? (???) <21FC6B02-6AC3-C4DB-0B50-98144802274C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
    0x7fff83b3d000 -     0x7fff83b85ff7  libvDSP.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <170DE04F-89AB-E295-0880-D69CAFBD7979> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fff83b88000 -     0x7fff83c22fff  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS 4.3 (???) <A7CD9E1F-C563-E940-130D-AA7E08C5A29F> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
    0x7fff83de9000 -     0x7fff83e9ffff  libobjc.A.dylib 227.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <F206BE6D-8777-AE6C-B367-7BEA76C14241> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff840da000 -     0x7fff8417afff  com.apple.LaunchServices 362.1 (362.1) <2740103A-6C71-D99F-8C6F-FA264546AD8F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
    0x7fff8417b000 -     0x7fff8417bff7  com.apple.Carbon 150 (152) <19B37B7B-1594-AD0A-7F14-FA2F85AD7241> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
    0x7fff84287000 -     0x7fff84287ff7  com.apple.CoreServices 44 (44) <210A4C56-BECB-E3E4-B6EE-7EC53E02265D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff84288000 -     0x7fff842b3ff7  libxslt.1.dylib 3.24.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <87A0B228-B24A-C426-C3FB-B40D7258DD49> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x7fff844f7000 -     0x7fff8461cfef  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox 1.6.3 (1.6.3) <4DCCD01F-7516-4240-09DC-EE553317D345> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
    0x7fff8461d000 -     0x7fff84672fef  com.apple.framework.familycontrols 2.0.1 (2010) <239940AC-2427-44C6-9E29-998D0ABECDF3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyControls.framework/Versions/A/FamilyControls
    0x7fff84675000 -     0x7fff84784fe7  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8) <36DA89A6-3AF5-86F2-BDD5-B94C7C0844D4> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff847e5000 -     0x7fff847f0ff7  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework 3.11.1 (3.11.1) <F0DDF27E-DB55-07CE-E548-C62095BE8167> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
    0x7fff84860000 -     0x7fff84876fef  libbsm.0.dylib ??? (???) <42D3023A-A1F7-4121-6417-FCC6B51B3E90> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x7fff84877000 -     0x7fff84879fff  com.apple.print.framework.Print 6.1 (237.1) <4513DB2F-737C-B43C-2D0E-23CD6E838014> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Print.framework/Versions/A/Print
    0x7fff84a77000 -     0x7fff84a7cff7  com.apple.CommonPanels 1.2.4 (91) <4D84803B-BD06-D80E-15AE-EFBE43F93605> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
    0x7fff84a83000 -     0x7fff84b43fff  libFontParser.dylib ??? (???) <A4F8189D-1D5B-2F8D-E78E-6D934A8E8407> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
    0x7fff84b44000 -     0x7fff84b64ff7  com.apple.DirectoryService.Framework 3.6 (621.3) <EDCAF7ED-36E1-121F-D294-5CEBC1C34C5A> /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService
    0x7fff84b65000 -     0x7fff84beafff  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore 6.2 (312.5) <E736F6DC-2E69-A14D-6BCF-69D14232F8B8> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
    0x7fff84e01000 -     0x7fff84e15ff7  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework 3.10.35 (3.10.35) <621B7415-A0B9-07A7-F313-36BEEDD7B132> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
    0x7fff84e16000 -     0x7fff84e1bfff  libGFXShared.dylib ??? (???) <1265FAEF-1C97-B339-28A4-4510589B067B> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
    0x7fff84e1c000 -     0x7fff85519067  com.apple.CoreGraphics 1.543.50 (???) <46A7D60C-0500-B96C-ECAD-1D658487D213> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
    0x7fff85684000 -     0x7fff8576afe7  com.apple.DesktopServices 1.5.7 (1.5.7) <8A697128-B6CA-E4A8-C200-6520D5A35FBE> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
    0x7fff8577f000 -     0x7fff85795fff  com.apple.ImageCapture 6.0 (6.0) <5B5AF8FB-C12A-B51F-94FC-3EC4698E818E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageCapture.framework/Versions/A/ImageCapture
    0x7fff857ea000 -     0x7fff85ff4fe7  libBLAS.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <FC941ECB-71D0-FAE3-DCBF-C5A619E594B8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff86025000 -     0x7fff86028ff7  libCoreVMClient.dylib ??? (???) <DBB2C09F-4BF4-326C-B775-B7A128C501E3> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
    0x7fff865b7000 -     0x7fff8666cfe7  com.apple.ink.framework 1.3.3 (107) <FFC46EE0-3544-A459-2AB9-94778A75E3D4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
    0x7fff86679000 -     0x7fff866b6fff  com.apple.LDAPFramework 2.0 (120.1) <16383FF5-0537-6298-73C9-473AEC9C149C> /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP
    0x7fff866b7000 -     0x7fff867d0fef  libGLProgrammability.dylib ??? (???) <B057FC52-6A97-F450-48D8-325A70423A53> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
    0x7fff867d1000 -     0x7fff8688afff  libsqlite3.dylib 9.6.0 (compatibility 9.0.0) <5A15E12A-AE8F-1A36-BBC7-564E7D7AD0FB> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x7fff8688b000 -     0x7fff86b0cfef  com.apple.Foundation 6.6.3 (751.29) <DAEDB589-9F59-9556-CF8D-07556317937B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff86b62000 -     0x7fff86be1fef  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 3.2.2 (3.2.2) <243E456E-7A74-BE76-FF18-E589BDCAA785> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
    0x7fff86be4000 -     0x7fff87027fef  libLAPACK.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <0CC61C98-FF51-67B3-F3D8-C5E430C201A9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff8703a000 -     0x7fff8703bff7  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit 1.6.3 (1.6.3) <D4183AC4-8A65-8368-A9AF-E2A13D18519C> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
    0x7fff870bf000 -     0x7fff870f7fef  libcups.2.dylib 2.8.0 (compatibility 2.0.0) <31A78904-A500-0DA9-0609-F1EB81383326> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
    0x7fff870f8000 -     0x7fff87184fef  SecurityFoundation ??? (???) <6860DE26-0D42-D1E8-CD7C-5B42D78C1E1D> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
    0x7fff87185000 -     0x7fff872faff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.3 (550.29) <48810602-63C3-994D-E563-DD02B16E76E1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff872fb000 -     0x7fff8731dff7  libexpat.1.dylib 7.2.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <8EC31253-B585-D05E-F35D-AE3292FB790B> /usr/lib/libexpat.1.dylib
    0x7fff8731e000 -     0x7fff873d3fe7  com.apple.ColorSync 4.6.3 (4.6.3) <AA93AD96-6974-9104-BF55-AF7A813C8A1B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
    0x7fff873dd000 -     0x7fff873e3ff7  com.apple.DiskArbitration 2.3 (2.3) <857F6E43-1EF4-7D53-351B-10DE0A8F992A> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fff873e4000 -     0x7fff874beff7  com.apple.vImage 4.0 (4.0) <354F34BF-B221-A3C9-2CA7-9BE5E14AD5AD> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff874bf000 -     0x7fff875b7ff7  libiconv.2.dylib 7.0.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <7E4ADB5A-CC77-DCFD-3E54-2F35A2C8D95A> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x7fff87764000 -     0x7fff87773fff  com.apple.NetFS 3.2.1 (3.2.1) <FF21DB1E-F425-1005-FB70-BC19CAF4006E> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
    0x7fff878e7000 -     0x7fff87c1afe7  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore 861.13 (861.13) <BC2F9B4E-D305-D717-D97E-EC78C7DE9EE9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff8802c000 -     0x7fff8802cff7  com.apple.ApplicationServices 38 (38) <10A0B9E9-4988-03D4-FC56-DDE231A02C63> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
    0x7fff88151000 -     0x7fff88311fef  libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <95E02DD0-ADEA-745B-E7FA-ABA064E4658C> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff88312000 -     0x7fff8833afff  com.apple.DictionaryServices 1.1.1 (1.1.1) <9FD709FC-23F0-F270-EAC1-C590CD516A36> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff8833b000 -     0x7fff88377fe7  libcurl.4.dylib 6.1.0 (compatibility 6.0.0) <1E041185-131C-C237-C250-38BE933A269A> /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
    0x7fff883b7000 -     0x7fff883c3fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib 1.0.5 (compatibility 1.0.0) <5C876577-ACB7-020C-F7DB-EE0135C3AB8D> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x7fff883c4000 -     0x7fff8864aff7  com.apple.security 6.1.1 (37594) <5EDDC08C-C95B-2D24-E1D2-D30D233AB065> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
    0x7fff88724000 -     0x7fff88775fe7  com.apple.HIServices 1.8.0 (???) <1ABA7802-C1E4-06A0-9035-2792CC915BF6> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
    0x7fff88782000 -     0x7fff8883fff7  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices 357 (357) <718F0719-DC9F-E392-7C64-9D7DFE3D02E2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fff88a7c000 -     0x7fff88a7cff7  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <DA9BFF01-40DF-EBD5-ABB7-787DAF2D77CF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff88a7d000 -     0x7fff88a92ff7  com.apple.LangAnalysis 1.6.6 (1.6.6) <DC999B32-BF41-94C8-0583-27D9AB463E8B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
    0x7fff88a93000 -     0x7fff88ab8fe7  com.apple.CoreVideo 1.6.1 (45.4) <B1516554-88BC-CF1E-5409-BFF27A73D1AF> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
    0x7fff88ab9000 -     0x7fff88adffe7  libJPEG.dylib ??? (???) <4060F3E2-BAD3-244F-D777-51BA16569DA4> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
    0x7fff88ae0000 -     0x7fff88b5efff  com.apple.CoreText 3.1.0 (???) <B740DA1D-EFD0-CCBF-F893-E3004FE58A98> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
    0x7fff88b5f000 -     0x7fff88b6eff7  com.apple.opengl 1.6.8 (1.6.8) <0CDC4F98-7981-A114-1778-AF171075138E> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
    0x7fff88b6f000 -     0x7fff88b8aff7  com.apple.openscripting 1.3.1 (???) <FD46A0FE-AC79-3EF7-AB4F-396D376DDE71> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OpenScripting.framework/Versions/A/OpenScripting
    0x7fff88b8b000 -     0x7fff88b8dfff  libRadiance.dylib ??? (???) <D67C08B6-4D4A-916D-E936-528E145A56E2> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
    0x7fff88b8e000 -     0x7fff88bd7fef  libGLU.dylib ??? (???) <34D118CD-F9EE-D023-FEBF-74581DEF31CD> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
    0x7fff88cf5000 -     0x7fff88ff3fe7  com.apple.HIToolbox 1.6.3 (???) <CF0C8524-FA82-3908-ACD0-A9176C704AED> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
    0x7fffffe00000 -     0x7fffffe01fff  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <95E02DD0-ADEA-745B-E7FA-ABA064E4658C> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Help debugging the problem is appreciated.

Best,
Mark

Comment: "SELECT * FROM Table" is an invalid query and should give a syntax error. Are you sure that's the actual query you are running?

Comment: What version of PHP, Apache and MySQL?  What operating system (Specifically)?  Does this only happen when requested through Apache, or does it happen when run from the command line as well?

Comment: Mark, Table is just a replacement for the table name.  Sorry for the confusion.  

ircmaxwell, Here's what phpmyadmin is telling me:
# Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) PHP/5.3.1
# MySQL client version: mysqlnd 5.0.5-dev - 081106 - $Revision: 289630 $

Answer (score 0):

A hint from ircmaxell led me to execute the script from the command line.  While error_reporting(E_ALL); was indeed on, the error wasn't displayed through apache.  But, from the command line I received:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2048 bytes)
```

While 256M is already a pretty large amount of memory, at least I have a lead to go on and will try splitting up the task.